# searchs that are directing traffic to my website

Tags: search

Have you ever seen those website who said: "Your are here because you looked at this terms in google", and then they show you your terms search? Anyone knows how do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTTP Referrer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) and read the GET Parameters

For example, in PHP use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Or with javascript:

```
document.referrer
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp